# pivot table: getting data from one column

Tags: mysql, count, pivot-table

lets say my table like:

```
Date                   Status
2010-01-02            
2010-01-03             accept
2010-01-03             accept
2010-01-03             reject
2010-01-03
2010-01-04             reject
```

i want if value null, it means accept. Beside that i want show the result like:

```
Date         Accept            Reject      
2010-01-02    1                 0
2010-01-03    3                 1
2010-01-04    0                 1
```

it means, calculate the amount of either accept or reject which contained in the status column. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE AS DATE, SUM( IF( 
STATUS =  'accept', 1, 0 ) ) AS Accept, SUM( IF( 
STATUS =  'reject', 1, 0 ) ) AS Reject
FROM pivot
GROUP BY DATE
```

updated** and working